# jquery .on('change' is not triggering while other events do

Tags: javascript, jquery

I dinamically add an input box in a table cell. The HTML I add is:

```
cell.html('<input type="text" id="finder" data-type="cittaNascita" value="'+value+'">');
```

The input is dinamically added so I then added:

```
$(document).on('change','#finder',function(){
    console.log('cerco altra citta');
});
```

but I never see the message in console.
This code works fine anyway:

```
$(document).on('keyup','#finder',function(){
    console.log('cerco altra citta');
});
```

so I expect it to be something related to `.on('change',` but even looking on SO my code should be working fine. What do I miss here?

Comment: Works just fine when I run it

Comment: Remember to trigger the change event, you have to leave the input, aka tab or press somewhere else

Comment: ok, that was the point... I was using it instead of keyup to determine if the user typed something... thanks for spotting the light!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.on('input'` event instead to fire the change event without actually leaving the input, it fires right after the value has changed.